# Conditional processing in SPSS

Tags: macros, conditional-statements, spss

I would like to conditionally process blocks of syntax where the condition is based on the active data set.

Within an SPSS macro, you can conditionally process a block of syntax using the !IF/!IFEND macro command. However, as far as I can tell, the user is required to explicitly give a value to the flag by either using the !LET command (!LET !FLAG = 1), or by using a Macro input variable. This is wildly different from my experience with other languages, where I can write code that has branching logic based on the data I'm working with.

Say that there is a block of syntax that I only want to run if there are at least 2 records in the active data set. I can create a variable in the data set which is equal to the number of records using the AGGREGATE function, but I can't find a way to make a macro variable equal to that value in a way that is usable as a !IF condition. Below is a very simple version of what I'd like to do.

```
COMPUTE DUMMY=1.  

AGGREGATE  
 /OUTFILE = * MODE = ADDVARIABLES  
 /BREAK DUMMY  
 /NUMBER_OF_CASES = N.  

!LET !N_CASES = NUMBER_OF_CASES.  

!IF (!N_CASES > 1) !THEN  
 MEANS TABLES = VAR1 VAR2 VAR3.  
!IFEND
```

Is what I'm attempting possible? Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a way to put a value from the dataset into a macro, which you can then use wherever you need - including in another macro.
First we'll make a little dataset to recreate your example:

```
data list free/var1 var2 var3.
begin data 
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 
end data.
* this will create the number of cases value:
AGGREGATE   /OUTFILE = * MODE = ADDVARIABLES   /BREAK  /NUMBER_OF_CASES = N.
```

Now we can send the value into a macro - by writing a separate syntax file with     the macro definition.

```
do if $casenum=1.
write out='SomePath\N_CASES.sps' /"define !N_CASES() ", NUMBER_OF_CASES, " !enddefine.".
end if.
exe.
insert file='SomePath\N_CASES.sps'.
```

The macro is now defined and you can use the value in calculations (e.g if you want to use it for analysis of a different dataset, or later in your syntax when the current data is not available).
for example:

```
compute just_checking= !N_CASES .
```

You can also use it in your macro as in your example - you'll see that the new macro can't read the `!N_CASES` macro as is, that's why you need the `!eval()` function:

```
define !cond_means ()
   !IF (!eval(!N_CASES) > 1) !THEN  
       MEANS TABLES = VAR1 VAR2 VAR3.  
   !IFEND
!enddefine.
```

Now running the macro will produce nothing if there is just one line in your data, and will run means if there was more than one line:

```
!cond_means.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I've tried implementing what you've recommended and it mostly works, but I'm having a particularly strange issue.

If I run my syntax once under conditions where the !IF conditional is satisfied, the !IF commands will run as expected. But then if I run my syntax again, this time in such a way where the !IF conditional is NOT satisfied, it will still run the !IF commands. If I then run the syntax AGAIN without changing anything, this time the !IF commands won't run.

It's as if the !IF conditional is relying on the value of my cond var from the last run.

Comment: For instance, if my !IF conditional is (!A =1), and I manually create an SPSS variable B = 1 and write that to !A (using the method you described), the !IF commands will run as expected. If I then run the syntax but with B = 0, the !IF commands will still run. If I run again with B=0, the !IF commands won't run.

If I run again with B=1, the !IF commands won't run. But then if I run it again with B=1, the !IF commands will run.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I'm trying to run the whole thing within a macro. The macro gets the data, writes a variable to a macro variable, then checks the condition in an !IF statement.

Comment: I should note that if I write my B variable to my macro variable !A, and then compute C = !A, C will show as the correct value. It's only when I attempt to use !A in an !IF condition that SPSS seems to be treating it as !A's previously assigned value.

`define Testing()

COMPUTE B=1.

DO IF $CASENUM=1.
WRITE OUT="H:\TEMP\MACRO_CONTROL.sps" 
    /"DEFINE !A() ", B, " !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
EXECUTE.

INSERT FILE = "H:\TEMP\MACRO_CONTROL.sps".
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE C = !A.

FREQ C.

!IF (!EVAL(!A)>=1) !THEN
FREQ var1.
!IFEND

!ENDDEFINE.`

Comment: (1) did you make sure to re-define !A (or !N_CASES in the example above) every time B (# of rows) changes, before trying to use it in a macro in your `!IF` statement? (2) running a macro definition within a macro may be problematic - try debugging by separating the macros, by printing out the value of B and of !A before and during the `!IF`.

Comment: In any case this sounds like an interesting problem - please consider wrapping this question up and posting the present problem as a new question.