# SPSS not updating macro values

Tags: spss

Suppose I have a variable in a dataset, let's say `X` with a unique value and I used it in a macro

```
DO IF $CASENUM=1.
WRITE OUTFILE "C:\TEMP\XVALUE.SPS"
    /"DEFINE !XVALUE()" X" !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
```

How can I use it in a if condition? I tried two ways but none worked

```
!IF(!EVAL(!XVALUE)=1) !THEN
CODE....
!IFEND.
!IF(!EVAL(!XVALUE)~=1) !THEN
CODE...
!IFEND.

!IF(!LENGTH(!BLANKS(!EVAL(!XVALUE))=1) !THEN
CODE...
!IFEND.
!IF(!LENGTH(!BLANKS(!EVAL(!XVALUE))~=1) !THEN
CODE...
!IFEND.
```

I don't know what is happening sometimes when `X` is bigger than 1 it correcly enter in the ~=1 clause, but it also enters this clause when `X=1`

I'm starting to learn about macros now so I'm probably doing some mistake, since I was able to create vectors using things like `VECTOR (!XVALUE, A10).` I thought I could also use it this way.

**EDIT:**

I did a test today and found the problem, but don't know how to fix it

```
COMPUTE Y=!EVAL(!XVALUE).
FREQ Y.
```

in a first run with `X=1` the macro entered in the right condition and the value showed in `Y` was `1`, but if I run it again in a situation where `X` was `3`, for example, the macro still enters in the condition where `X` is `1` and the value showed in `Y` still is `1`, so it's not updating. What I don't understand is the fact that in `XVALUE.SPS` macro the value is updated for `3`.

**Note:** In every call inside a macro the value is being updated with

```
INSERT FILE = 'C:\TEMP\XVALUE.SPS'
```

but for some reason SPSS is not updating it.

**EDIT2:** If I run the code with X = 1 and then after it with X = 3 it not works immediately, but if I run again the code in the situation where X=3 it will works fine, so I don't know if it's a windows problem not updating `XVALUE.SPS` file in time or is a problem in SPSS

**EDIT3:** I'm calling `!XVALUE` inside of another macro definition.

**EDIT4: Macro Example**

```
*NEED TO HAVE A C:\TEMP\ FOLDER IN YOUR COMPUTER OR JUST CHANGE THE PATH.
DEFINE !TEST()
DO IF $CASENUM=1.
WRITE OUTFILE "C:\TEMP\XVALUE.SPS"
    /"DEFINE !XVALUE()" X" !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
EXEC.
INSERT FILE = 'C:\TEMP\XVALUE.SPS'.
COMPUTE Y=!EVAL(!XVALUE).
FREQ Y.
!ENDDEFINE.

DATA LIST /ID 1.
BEGIN DATA
1
END DATA.

COMPUTE X=1.
!TEST.

COMPUTE X=2.
!TEST.
```

Comment: I think in the macro you need to compare to `"1"` instead of `1`.

Comment: @eli-k it didn't work, the problem is SPSS not updating the value of `!XVALUE` in subsequent calls of the macro. Someone already reported the same problem in comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329384/conditional-processing-in-spss  . Basically you need to do two calls of the same function for it update.

Comment: This is wrong also: `COMPUTE Y=!EVAL(!XVALUE).`. You only need `!EVAL` inside a macro definition. In regular syntax you can use  `COMPUTE Y=!XVALUE .`

Comment: @eli-k I'm using it inside another macro definition, so I need !EVAL right? .. The compute was just an example, thing is, I'm calling !XVALUE inside of another macro.

Comment: Would `INSERT FILE = 'C:\TEMP\XVALUE.SPS' /CLOSE.`  help?

Comment: @VonC No, it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This not solve the entire problem since I still can't use the macro value `XVALUE`in conditions

I created a temporary workaround for this problem. Since SPSS is not updating `!XVALUE` in subsequent calls I made some adjustment and now the macro creates a new `!XVALUE` parameter each time it runs using the system time as reference

```
*NEED TO HAVE A C:\TEMP\ FOLDER IN YOUR COMPUTER OR JUST CHANGE THE PATH.
DEFINE !TEST()
DO IF $CASENUM=1.
STRING #TIME(A11).
COMPUTE #TIME=STRING($TIME, F11.0).
WRITE OUTFILE "C:\TEMP\TIME.SPS"
    /"DEFINE !TIME ()" #TIME " !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
EXEC.
INSERT FILE="C:\TEMP\TIME.SPS".

DO IF $CASENUM=1.
WRITE OUTFILE !QUOTE(!CONCAT("C:\TEMP\XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME),".SPS"))
    /!QUOTE(!CONCAT("DEFINE !XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME),"()")) X" !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
EXEC.
INSERT FILE =!QUOTE(!CONCAT("C:\TEMP\XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME),".SPS")).
COMPUTE Y=!EVAL(!CONCAT("!XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME))).
FREQ Y.
!ENDDEFINE.


DATA LIST /ID 1.
BEGIN DATA
1
END DATA.

COMPUTE X=1.
!TEST.

COMPUTE X=2.
!TEST.
```

Now I'm with a new problem can't use it in `!IF !THEN !IFEND`. Let's say I want to do something like

```
*NEED TO HAVE A C:\TEMP\ FOLDER IN YOUR COMPUTER OR JUST CHANGE THE PATH.
DEFINE !TEST()
DO IF $CASENUM=1.
STRING #TIME(A11).
COMPUTE #TIME=STRING($TIME, F11.0).
WRITE OUTFILE "C:\TEMP\TIME.SPS"
    /"DEFINE !TIME ()" #TIME " !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
EXEC.
INSERT FILE="C:\TEMP\TIME.SPS".

DO IF $CASENUM=1.
WRITE OUTFILE !QUOTE(!CONCAT("C:\TEMP\XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME),".SPS"))
    /!QUOTE(!CONCAT("DEFINE !XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME),"()")) X" !ENDDEFINE.".
END IF.
EXEC.
INSERT FILE =!QUOTE(!CONCAT("C:\TEMP\XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME),".SPS")).
!LET !Y=!EVAL(!CONCAT("!XVALUE_",!EVAL(!TIME))).

!IF(!Y=1) !THEN
PRINT /'OK'.
!IFEND.

!IF(!Y~=1) !THEN
PRINT /'NOT OK'.
!IFEND.

!ENDDEFINE.


DATA LIST /ID 1.
BEGIN DATA
1
END DATA.

COMPUTE X=1.
!TEST.

COMPUTE X=2.
!TEST.
```

the conditions are not making sense, even when X=1 it prints NOT OK and I did a check of the values doing

```
COMPUTE CHECK=!Y.
```